# Accidentally posted question on wrong site

Tags: discussion

I was on Salesforce Stack Exchange to post a question and I saw one of these pretty green indicators on the top bar that said I earned 5 points, so naturally I got distracted and click on it and then the question. What I didn't pay attention to was that I changed to the Stack Overflow site.

So I posted my Salesforce question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657445/authenticating-salesforce-users-via-jwt-against-asp-net-web-application

While this question is relevant to Stack Overflow as well, it might do better on the Salesforce Stack Exchange site. But then again, it may not.

Should I just let this question ride on Stack Overflow?

What if I don't get any action? Should I delete it and post on Salesforce Stack Exchange instead?

Comment: If you really want to have it on the other site instead, just delete it now.  Before it gets a bunch of activity here.  Then post on the appropriate site.

Comment: It's close to the borderline, but that feels like more of a Salesforce question to me. I think you're more likely to get an answer on the SF site.

Comment: Thanks. I moved it to Salesforce Stack Exchange. I appreciate the responses.